# DBT: Package names must be unique in a project. Please rename one of these packages

Tags: dbt

I get the following error while running the command

`dbt run`

`dbt found more than one package with the name "my_project_name" included in this project. Package names must be unique in a project. Please rename one of these packages.`

I've used the same "my_project_name" in profiles.yml and dbt_project.yml as suggested and do not have any other package.

How can I check where this error is coming from? Any particular parameter that needs to be cross verified?

Thanks in advance!

Update:

```
profiles.yml

my_project_name:
  outputs:

    dev:
      type: postgres
      threads: 4
      host: hostname
      port: 5432
      user: username
      pass: password
      dbname: db
      schema: schemaname

    prod:
      type: postgres
      threads: [1 or more]
      host: [host]
      port: [port]
      user: [prod_username]
      pass: [prod_password]
      dbname: [dbname]
      schema: [prod_schema]

  target: dev
```

```
dbt_project.yml

config-version: 2
name: my_project_name
version: 1.0

profile: my_project_name

macro-paths: ["macros"]
```

Comment: Post your packages.yml and your dbt_project.yml.

Comment: @AdamKipnis I've added my yml's

Comment: I was asking for packages.yml for the dependencies, not profiles.yml. I'm guessing that means you don't have any? Your dbt_project.yml looks incomplete. Where are the rest of the paths and model configurations for the project? What happens if you change the project name to something more descriptive?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues. To resolve that, in your dbt_project.yml

Change the name and use the same name in the models sections

```yaml
name: 'airscholar_dbt_bigquery' # this was previously dbt_bigquery
version: '1.0.0'
config-version: 2

profile: 'dbt_bigquery'

model-paths: ["models"]
analysis-paths: ["analyses"]
test-paths: ["tests"]
seed-paths: ["seeds"]
macro-paths: ["macros"]
snapshot-paths: ["snapshots"]

clean-targets: 
  - "target"
  - "dbt_packages"


models:
  airscholar_dbt_bigquery: # also previously dbt_bigquery
    example:
      +materialized: view
```

You can then run `dbt run`. You should be good afterwards.